# quarter hour wont be accurate

Tags: javascript, date

Why wont quarterHours show me 1,2,3,4? or all of the numbers?
im trying to get each 15 minutes.

is the nextlaunch not calculating the next 15 minute right?

why, wont it calculate the next 15 minutes correctly ?

Im expecting it quarterHours to output all the 15 minutes.

```
X:15 = 1
X:30 = 2
X:45 = 3
X:00 = 4 or 0
```

current outcome:

```
    4/9/2016 @ 18:30:0
fiddle.jshell.net/:60 2
fiddle.jshell.net/:59 4/9/2016 @ 18:30:0
fiddle.jshell.net/:60 2
fiddle.jshell.net/:59 4/9/2016 @ 18:30:0
fiddle.jshell.net/:60 2
fiddle.jshell.net/:59 4/9/2016 @ 19:0:0
fiddle.jshell.net/:60 0
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2x1jmzb/

code:

```
   var y = 1;

   while(y <= 4) {
      var interval = (900000 * y);
    var nextlaunch = new Date(Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()/interval)*interval);
   var datetime = "" + nextlaunch.getDate() + "/"
                + (nextlaunch.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + nextlaunch.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + nextlaunch.getHours() + ":"  
                + nextlaunch.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + nextlaunch.getSeconds();

  quarterHours = Math.round(nextlaunch.getMinutes()/15);
  console.log(datetime);
  console.log(quarterHours);
  y++;
   }
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would exspect the nextlaunch to have the time for the 4 next 15 mins, 
but in this case, it should be 4 quarterhours an hour.
15 = 1
30 = 2
45 = 3
00 = 4/0
but that is not working

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. i updated my topic. is that better?

Comment: But why not use a simple assignment? I.e `if (.getMinutes() <= 15) quarterHours = 1; else if (.getMinutes() <= 30) quarterHours = 2;` etc, etc. As it stands, you'll only get back 4 if the minutes are greater than 60. 59/15 = 3.93  (int)3.93 = 3

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/ucckLbfL/2/

Comment: If the goal is to take a minutes value and turn 0-14 => 0, 15-29 => 1, 30 => 44 => 2, and 45-59 => 3, then it's just `Math.floor(dt.getMinutes() / 15)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code:

```js
function pad(n) {
    return ('0'+n).substr(-2);
}
   
var interval = 15 * 60 * 1000; // = # miliseconds in 15 minutes
var nextlaunch = new Date(Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()/interval)*interval);
for (var y = 1; y <= 4; y++) {
    var datetime = pad(nextlaunch.getDate()) + "/"
                + pad((nextlaunch.getMonth()+1))  + "/" 
                + nextlaunch.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + pad(nextlaunch.getHours()) + ":"  
                + pad(nextlaunch.getMinutes()) + ":" 
                + pad(nextlaunch.getSeconds());
    quarterHours = Math.round(nextlaunch.getMinutes()/15);
    console.log(datetime);
    nextlaunch.setMinutes(nextlaunch.getMinutes()+15);
}
```

The idea is that you increase the `nextlaunch` variable in the loop by adding 15 minutes to it. Its initial value can be set outside of the loop, with the use of the appropriate interval.

I added a function to do proper padding with zeroes in the date format. You might consider using a library to work with dates, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g2x1jmzb/8/ @trincot it works. but why does this code ignore the new hour?

Comment: Because you output the date object, not the string-formatted date. In the first case, it displays the UTC date. So, better first format the date, and display `datetime` instead of `nextlaunch`.